# ¿Cual es el error en mi programa?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Por alguna razón se ejecuta todo el código sin dejarme añadir el resto de información necesaria para que de el calculo que se necesita.

La idea es hacer que el programa muestre cuántos ganaron todos los exámenes, cuántos ganaron sólo uno y cuántos ganaron sólo el ultimo, pero se queda trabado desde el primer `cin`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int e1,e2,e3,at=0,a1=0,au=0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        cout<<i<<". Digite la nota del primer examen : "<<endl; cin>>e1;
        cout<<i<<". Digite la nota del segundo examen : "<<endl; cin>>e2;
        cout<<i<<". Digite la nota del tercer examen : "<<endl; cin>>e3;
        cout<<"\n";
        
        if((e1>=3.1) && (e2>=3.1) && (e3>=3.1)){
            at++;
        }
        
        if((e1>=3.1) || (e2>=3.1) || (e3>=3.1)){
            a1++;
        }
        
        if((e1<3.1) && (e2<3.1) && (e3>=3.1)){
            au++;
        }
    }
    
    cout<<"Alumnos que aprobaron todos los examenes : " <<at<<endl;
    cout<<"Alumnos que aprobaron al menos un examen : " <<a1<<endl;
    cout<<"Alumnos que aprobaron solo el ultimo examen : " <<au<<endl;
    
    
    getch();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tu codigo me funciona como deberia. ¿Cual fué la entrada que pusiste?. Porque cuando inserto double o decimales me sale los sintomas que describes, pero cuando inserto entero o int me funciona perfectamente. El codigo pide la entrada 6 veces. Y mi compilador es dev-cpp. Dicho esto. Creo que el ploblema viene porque la entrada es un decimal, pero las variables son enteras. Recomiendo que uses: double. en vez de int.

Comment: Ah si muchisimas gracias si es por la entrada, fue una confucion por el cambio de las calificaciones en cada pais, mil gracias bro